# how to save kernel panic to file in embedded devices

Tags: logging, kernel, panic

I'm develop a embedded device, In debug mode, I use NFS to mount my app to device,  telnet to the device, then run my app. the device's serial port console is not available  Some times, the  kernel fatal panic, but I don't know when. the network is down, and I can't telnet to the device get any panic message, I want to save panic message to file and check it after next boot, any one know how? thanks!

Some info about the device
OS: linux 3.0.8
ram: 64M
spi:16M
nand:256M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194757

```sh
kernel.core_pattern = /var/crash/core.%t.%p
kernel.panic=10
kernel.unknown_nmi_panic=1
```